# Insert into table which contains nested-table inside (Object in Oracle)

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have script of creating here:

```
create type Ingredients_type as object (
Ingredient_ID varchar2(20),
Ingredient_Name varchar2(50),
ICalori int,
IPretein int);

create type Food_type as object (
FoodType_ID varchar2(20),
FoodType_Name varchar2(50));

create type FoodIngredients_type as object (
Ingredients Ingredients_type,
Amount int);

create type FoodIngredients_table as table of FoodIngredients_type;

create table Foods(
Food_ID varchar2(20),
Food_Name varchar2(50),
FType Food_type,
FIngredients FoodIngredients_table,
Cost int,
FCalori int,
FProtein int)
nested table FIngredients store as FIngredients_col;
```

But I can't insert values into `Foods`. I have counted enough arguments and don't know where is missing or redundancy...

```
insert into Foods values ('F1', 'Food #1', Food_type('FT1', 'Noodle'),
FoodIngredients_table(FoodIngredients_type(Ingredients_type('I1','Ingredient #1', 0, 0), 10,
                                           Ingredients_type('I2','Ingredient #2', 0, 0), 20)), 
                                           1000, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple mistake, I forget to call `FoodIngredients_type`. Sorry for disturbing all again.

```
insert into Foods values ('F1', 'Food #1', Food_type('FT1', 'Noodle'),
FoodIngredients_table(FoodIngredients_type(Ingredients_type('I1','Ingredient #1', 0, 0), 10),
                      FoodIngredients_type(Ingredients_type('I2','Ingredient #2', 0, 0), 20)), 
                                           1000, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the system knows that the question is Not Open anymore.